# В чем передавать данные?

Tags: java, сокет, строки, сокеты

Пишу на `java` чат для осознания того, как работают сокеты. Сейчас данные передаются `String`'ами и читаются соответственно через `Data[Input/Output]Stream`. Некоторое время назад появились некоторые проблемы связанные, допустим, с `readUTF()` и прочими вещами типа авторизации и так далее. Собственно вопрос , есть ли способ передачи информации между клиентом и сервером не через `String`? Знаю, что есть сериализация, но к месту ли она тут?

Comment: Если с обеих сторон ваш код, и насчет совместимости думать не надо, то почему бы и не встроенная сериализация. С одной стороны закинули объект, с другой стороны приняли объект, преобразованием ваших структур данных в байты и обратно занимается ваша библиотека. Удобно.

Comment: @zRrr Как раз таки с обеих сторон разный код, поэтому я и думаю, что она тут не к месту.

Comment: тогда JSON идеально подходит для rest api, можно и XML